# Add moveclips on stage when elements of an array are clicked in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an array with six buttons called "sostaletters" and an array with six elements called "addedletters".  What I want is every time a button is been clicked a new movieclip from the array "addedletters" to be added on stage. For example if the third element of the array "sostaletters" is been clicked then  the third element of the array  "addedletters"  to be added on stage. How i can do that?

This is what i have done for my  array "sostaletters"

```
 var sostaletters:Array = [a7,a17,a24,a1,a18] 
    for each (var letter:MovieClip in sostaletters) {
        letter.buttonMode = true;
        letter.isClicked = false;
        letter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kanoklick2);
        function kanoklick2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
        event.target.alpha = 0.5;
        if(event.currentTarget.isClicked == false){
        clickCount2 ++;
        event.currentTarget.isClicked = true;
        sostaletters[i].x = positionsArray[i].xPos;
        sostaletters[i].y = positionsArray[i].yPos;
        setChildIndex(MovieClip(e.currentTarget), numChildren - 1);
}
if(clickCount2 == sostaletters.length){
    addChild(welldoneman);
    myTimer.start();
       if (contains(kremmala)) {
        removeChild(kremmala)
        }
for (var i:int= 0; i< wrongletters.length; i++) 
{
    wrongletters[i].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kanoklick);
 }
for (var o:int= 0; o< sostaletters.length; o++) 
{
    sostaletters[o].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kanoklick2);
}
trace("All buttons have been clicked");

}
}
}
```

Comment: The letters on the stage that are being clicked are instances of a class, right? Can that class be given a property that defines what number element it is in the array? If so, you could then do target._elemNum in the click event to retrieve a value that could be fed into the other array to pull out the element you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Neal Davis has already gave a right answer. But I shall make a code review for more clarity. See my comments in the code.

```
var sostaletters:Array = [a7,a17,a24,a1,a18] 
// "sostaletters" is an Array. So it is better to use iteration by index
for each (var letter:MovieClip in sostaletters) {
   letter.buttonMode = true;
   letter.isClicked = false;
   letter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kanoklick2);

   // You will create "kanoklick2" function at each iteration. 
   // Move this declaration from this loop
   function kanoklick2(event:MouseEvent):void {
     event.target.alpha = 0.5;

     // There is no need to compare a boolean property with "false" or "true"
     // You can write "if(event.currentTarget.isClicked)"
     if(event.currentTarget.isClicked == false) {
       clickCount2 ++;
       event.currentTarget.isClicked = true;

       // You declare an "i" variable below. 
       // So the compiler will not fire en error.
       // But you will not get an index of the current letter.
       sostaletters[i].x = positionsArray[i].xPos;
       sostaletters[i].y = positionsArray[i].yPos;
       setChildIndex(MovieClip(e.currentTarget), numChildren - 1);
     }

     // If number of "sostaletters" are not changed
     // you can save its value in a variable for an example "sostalettersNum"
     if (clickCount2 == sostaletters.length) {
       addChild(welldoneman);
       myTimer.start();
       if (contains(kremmala)) {
         removeChild(kremmala)
       }

       // You declare an "i" variable. And use it above to get a current letter. 
       // But an "i" will not contain its index. 
       // It will be equal to "wrongletters.length"
       for (var i:int= 0; i
```